# SQOOP --where is not working with --query

Tags: sqoop

The WHERE clause is NOT WORKING with `--where` along with `--query`

`sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username "retail_dba" --password "cloudera" --target-dir "/user/cloudera/sqoop_import_tables/departments21" --query "select * From orders where \$CONDITIONS" --where "order_id < 8000" --split-by order_id;`

Logs shows "WHERE ( order_id < 8000 )" - where condition is ignored in BoundingValsQuery:-

```
16/08/31 12:20:26 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
16/08/31 12:20:26 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(order_id), MAX(order_id) FROM (select * From orders where  (1 = 1) ) AS t1
16/08/31 12:20:26 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 17220; Num splits: 4 from: 1 to: 68883
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter: Splits: [                           1 to                       68,883] into 4 parts
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                            1
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                       17,222
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                       34,443
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                       51,663
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                       68,883
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound 'order_id >= 1' and upper bound 'order_id < 17222'
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound 'order_id >= 17222' and upper bound 'order_id < 34443'
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound 'order_id >= 34443' and upper bound 'order_id < 51663'
16/08/31 12:20:26 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound 'order_id >= 51663' and upper bound 'order_id <= 68883'
16/08/31 12:20:26 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
16/08/31 12:20:26 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1472622587119_0024
```

The WHERE clause is WORKING fine with `--where` along with `--table`.

`sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username "retail_dba" --password "cloudera" --target-dir "/user/cloudera/sqoop_import_tables/departments22" --table orders --where "order_id < 8000" --split-by order_id`

Logs shows "WHERE ( order_id < 8000 )" - where condition is honoured.

```
16/08/31 12:34:35 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(`order_id`), MAX(`order_id`) FROM `orders` WHERE ( order_id < 8000 )
16/08/31 12:34:35 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 1999; Num splits: 4 from: 1 to: 7999
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter: Splits: [                           1 to                        7,999] into 4 parts
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                            1
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        2,001
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        4,001
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        6,000
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        7,999
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound '`order_id` >= 1' and upper bound '`order_id` < 2001'
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound '`order_id` >= 2001' and upper bound '`order_id` < 4001'
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound '`order_id` >= 4001' and upper bound '`order_id` < 6000'
16/08/31 12:34:35 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound '`order_id` >= 6000' and upper bound '`order_id` <= 7999'
16/08/31 12:34:35 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
```

1. Any logcal reason, why the `--where` option is not working with `--query` and working with `--table`?
2. In case of `--query` option, how can we use `--where` to provide additional filtering?
3. Any documentation around this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do filtering inside of the freeform query, e.g.,

```
... --query "select ... where order_id < 8000 and \$CONDITIONS" ...
```

Of course, using the `query` option here is unnecessary, because you're selecting all rows anyway.  So you might as well just drop the query part and include `--where "order_id < 8000"`.

Basically, it's one or the other (`--query` or `--where`); using both doesn't make sense.  See the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) for more information.

Comment: Thank you dmdmdmdmdmd. Its working with the example mentioned:
 For example, a double quoted query may look like: "SELECT * FROM x WHERE a='foo' AND \$CONDITIONS"

Just curious, why we can not use --where along with --query, any specific restrictions from sqoop side??

Comment: @Rameshdevarakonda see dev's answer below.  And if my answer addresses your question appropriately, consider "accepting" it by clicking the checkmark to its left.  This way, the question will not pop up later on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Your all other questions are already answered. I am picking -

> why the `--where` option is not working with `--query` and working with `--table`?

Because it can lead to **ambiguous** results.

For example,

you put `--where id > 100`

and `--query "select * from table where order_id < 100 and \$CONDITIONS"`

Now what would you expect sqoop to return?

So, this can be confusing and leads to wrong results from users perspective.

you can always put your WHERE condition in `--query`. So there is no need of `--where` tag with `--query` tag.

**`--where` is a subset of `--query`**.

Comment: Enven if you arrange your query like this with --query & --where. 
The --where condition is not working. 
Looks like --query & --where is mutually exclusive switches for the sqoop:
 
sqoop import --connect "XXXX" --username "x" --password "y" --target-dir "/dir" --query "select * From orders where order_id >10 and  \$CONDITIONS" --where "order_id < 20" --split-by order_id;

The question originally for a team, who want to pass as many args to the where dynamically to a script- which runs daily- instead of adding lengthy query they want to read simple where conditions out side script.

Answer (score 0):

with free form query (--query) if you use --where it will be ignored by sqoop. sqoop will give prefrence to the where clause mentioned in the --query....

Comment: any documentation which states that aditya?