# SQOOP import error with --query without where $CONDITION

Tags: sqoop

I have a `dept_nopk` table . this table has two columns, `department_id` and `department_name` and this table does not have any primary key. I am trying to import this table in HDFS using following SQOOP command.

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db"
--username useranem
--password pass
--query "select * from dept_nopk where department_id <> 1000"
--target-dir /user/cloudera/departments
-m 1
```

but it is  giving following error:

```
java.io.IOException: query[select * from dept_nopk where department_id <> 1000] must contain $CONDITION in where clause
```

My questions now are:

1) Why am I getting this error when I have already specified that the number of maps are just 1?  is it necessary to put `$CONDITION`  in my `where` clause?

2) The second time I changed my query as follows

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db"
--username useranem
--password pass
--query "select * from dept_nopk where \$CONDITIONS"
--target-dir /user/cloudera/departments
--where "department_id <> 8000"            
-m 1
```

I used `--where` for the `department_id<>8000` and specified `\$CONDITIONS`. Now I did not get any error but in the results it imported rows with `department_id =8000` as well, i.e. it totally ignored the `--where` argument. Why?

3) I tried following and it worked perfectly.

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db"
--username useranem
--password pass
--query "select * from dept_nopk where department_id <> 8000 and \$CONDITIONS"
--target-dir /user/cloudera/departments          
-m 1
```

Could you please explain the reasoning behind the errors described in 1) and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1

Adding `$CONDITION` is mandatory in Sqoop even with 1 mapper because Sqoop transform queries for 1 mapper like -

To fetch metadata:

```
select * from dept_nopk where 1 = 0
```

replaces `\$CONDITIONS` with 1= 0

to fetch all data:

```
select * from dept_nopk where 1 = 1
```

replaces `\$CONDITIONS` with 1= 1

> Question 2

Check similar question : [SQOOP --where is not working with --query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257774/sqoop-where-is-not-working-with-query)

Comment: Thanks dev, your answers are helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

*--where is mutually exclusive with --query (so ignored if included)
[Logically, u r adding --query to add your where caluse]

*$CONDITIONS is NOT related to your conditions(where clause). It (is required in --query and) is used internally to parallelize the results even though mappers are more than 1. It works with --split-by argument.